# Custom exception handling error

Tags: java, exception

I have custom exception which extends JSONException and i want my method to throw this exception rather than using try catch in my method.

When i use my exception, IDE still warning me to handle JSON exception.

**Exception**

```
public class NoBorderException extends JSONException {
    public NoBorderException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public  String getMessage(){
        return  super.getMessage();
    } 
}
```

**Method** - unhandled JSON exception

```
    private void loadNeighboringCountries(String data) throws NoBorderException {
            final JSONArray arrBorders = new JSONArray(data);
            System.out.print(arrBorders.get(0));
```

**Method**  - No problem

```
private void loadNeighboringCountries(String data) throws JSONException{
        final JSONArray arrBorders = new JSONArray(data);
        System.out.print(arrBorders.get(0));
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The `JSONArray` constructor (and indeed the `get` method) throws a `JSONException`. Your method is only declared to throw a `NoBorderException` and not the superclass, which means that `JSONException` remains unhandled.

In short, the declaration `throws NoBorderException` covers any subclass of `NoBorderException`, but not its superclass `JSONException`.

If you want this method to throw your custom exception type then you will need to do something like this:

```
try {
    final JSONArray arrBorders = new JSONArray(data);
    System.out.print(arrBorders.get(0));
}
catch (JSONArray e) {
    throw new NoBorderException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i know that when i surround it it wors, but i havent understood what is the problem with this ? MyException extends JsonException so, i assume that, it should work ??

Comment: As I mentioned in the post: the declaration `throws NoBorderException` covers any _subclass_ of `NoBorderException`, but _not_ its superclass `JSONException`.

Comment: Ok thanks, so there are no same hierarcy between JSONexception -> Exception and NoBorderException->JSONexception.

Comment: There is a hierarchy, but you've got it the wrong way round. You need to declare the _most general_ exception class that your method throws (or, indeed, declare multiple `throws`). In this case `JSONException` is more general than `NoBorderException`, since it is the superclass.